# Como recuperar o Resultado de uma tabela, em um Loop For

Tags: javascript

Pessoal tenho uma tabela em javascript, ela esta sendo estruturado por um loop for, porem eu preciso calcular o resultado dela..segue o código..

```
for(i = 1; i<=30; i++) {
var maximo = 5;
var a = parseInt(Math.random()*maximo+1);
var b = parseInt(Math.random()*maximo+1);
var names = ["João", "Maria"];
var randomNames = (names[Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1]);

table += '<tr><td>'+i+'</td>';
table += '<td>'+ a +'</td>';
table += '<td>'+ b +'</td>';
table += '<td>'+ randomNames +'</td>';
table += '<td>'+ f1 +'</td>';
table += '<td>'+ f2 +'</td>';
table += '<td>'+ f3 +'</td></tr>';

}

table += '</tbody></table>';
```

nos campos f1, f2, f3, vai ser exibidos 2 valores diferentes.. ou é Maça ou Pera, o loop vai percorrer 30 linhas na tabela ao final preciso saber quantas Maças e quantas Peras apareceram no Total, quebrei a cuca aqui e não consegui resolver essa questão, agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

olá, abaixo uma possível solução:

preencha um array com length = 30 das palavras que vc quer:

```
var names = ["João", "Maria"];
var array = [];
for(var i=0; i< 30; i++){
    array.push(names[Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1]);
}
```

preencha a tabela com os valores do array e depois recupere a quantidade de vezes que repetem por:

```
// para a posição 0, no caso, João
array.reduce((a,e)=>{ return e==names[0] ? a=a+1 : a }, 0)

// para a posição 1, no caso, Maria
array.reduce((a,e)=>{ return e==names[1] ? a=a+1 : a }, 0)
```